# What do realize() and prefetch() mean exactly?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, nokia

What do `realize()` and `prefetch()` mean exactly?

for Audio files:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SMS.mp3");
player = Manager.createPlayer(is,"audio/mpeg")
player.realize();
player.prefetch();
player.start();
```

for Camera...

```
player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
player.realize();
videoControl = (VideoControl)player.getControl("VideoControl");
Canvas canvas = new VLCCanvas( videoControl);
d.setCurrent(canvas);
player.start();
```

so here in the above code some times it uses only realize() and some times prefetch() too. But what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at the [API docs](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Player.html) which talk about exactly this. I imagine that the API is flexible and can execute uncalled state transitions when a later one is specified to be executed (i.e., realisation without prefetch being called first).